# Node.js + Express server specific static files extremely slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-side

I have this very weird problem.
I'm running an Express (Node.js) server with a React front-end.
Ever since I've began developing it, it has run cleanly and without issues, taking a few seconds to load every refresh.

Today it started loading horribly - From 20 seconds to a full minute for a 2MB app.

I checked and found that there are two files - `vendor.bundle.js` and `bundle.js` (Created by gulp and contain the app code and external dependencies) that take much more time to load than others.
Each of them weighs about 700KB and takes about 10 seconds to load.
As a comparison, `vendor.js` weighs about 400KB and takes 1 second to load.

If that's not enough - I tried running the boilerplate for the app I'm using (It's an app from a tutorial so it weighs about the same) and it takes about 6 seconds to load.

I have absolutely no idea why is this happening or why is there a difference with these specific files.

Do you have any ideas? I've become quite desperate.

Thanks for any help.

Express static file serving and a bit of the sorrounding:

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//Static files being served
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(require('./routes/user-routes'));

app.all('/api/*', jwt_middleware({ secret: config.secret }).unless({path: ['/login']}));
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
    res.status(401).send('invalid token...');
  }
});

app.get('*', function (request, response, next){
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
});
```

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? that would confirm or rule out it being a problem with your code.

Comment: I've tried Internet Explorer on my PC & Chrome on my mobile once with my wifi and once with 3g.
But also, with a different (but similar) project it ran fine.

Comment: then... it's only happening in chrome? or am i misunderstanding your comment.

Comment: It's happening in all of them, e.g. the problem is the project. That theorem is strengthened by the fact that when I ran a different project, it loaded nicely.

Comment: Can any downvoters add a comment saying what they think is wrong with the answer? I'm sorry if you think it's unclear but just downvoting it isn't helpful.

Comment: Include how these files are being served. Are they being served by nginx? apache? node.js? iis? include more details on whichever one it's being served by. Include information from the network tab that shows what part of the request is taking so long. There's just not enough information for us to debug this. Your question is basically: "My js file is loading slow, please help."

Comment: I don't know what would be useful. Since I can't understand what's going on, I won't just blurt out all of my code. Would you prefer that? Instead I wait for an idea to where it could be coming from, such as your comment, and follow accordingly.

Comment: You could try installing the debug module and logging everything, it might give you some insight into what within the static module is slowing that particular file.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful indeed. Seems like the problem comes and goes, as right now it's back to normal. Will try the debug module if it comes again.

Comment: as far as votes... votes are completely separate from comments. I downvoted because there's not enough information to solve the problem. I didn't leave a comment because i do not really have the time to go through a long back and forth process of getting more information from you, i needed to move on to another project at the time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94035/discussion-between-neta-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 0):

Went away on its own, will try the debug module if it comes back.

Comment: note... you may not need to actually install it, just adding the environment variable might be enough. `DEBUG = *` express uses it, and it's plugins may too.